Find by example in Spring Data JPA
Suppose I have an entity with a lot of fields. Instead of passing them separately and bloating the parameter list, I want to pass a whole entity instead.
How do I achieve it in Spring Data JPA?
For the purpose of the question, I'll make the entity tiny, but you can imagine it a lot bigger.
package com.example.socks_api.dao;

import com.example.socks_api.data.entity.Socks;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.RepositoryDefinition;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.UUID;

@RepositoryDefinition(idClass = UUID.class, domainClass = Socks.class)
public interface SocksDao {

    // this query will make the app fail at start-up
    @Query("""
            SELECT Socks s
            WHERE s.color = :socks.color
            AND s.cottonContent = :socks.cottonContent
            """)
    Socks findBy(@Param("socks") Socks socks);
}

package com.example.socks_api.data.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Socks {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    private String color;
    @Column(name = "cotton_content")
    private Integer cottonContent;
    private BigInteger quantity;
}

Java 17, Spring Boot 3

This question is similar to: Spring JPA findAll() adding additional columns in where clause. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can to use:
org.springframework.data.domain.Example

public Socks findByExample() {
    Socks socks = new Socks(params by constractor);
    return findByExample(socks);
}

public Socks findByExample(Socks sock) {
    return socksDao.findOne(Example.of(sock));
}

